# Can anyone tell what's the issue with the return statement in the code?

Tags: python-2.7

First version of the code:

This returns a list but that contains only few file names instead of returning a list of all the file names.

```
import os

def dig(directory):
    c_path = []
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            c_path.append(path)
        else:
            dig(path)
    return c_path

directory = str(input("Enter Directory: "))
files = dig(directory)
for f in files:
    print f
```

Second version of the code:

This version does not return the list but it prints the list inside the function and that prints all the file names, so i don't know what's the issue with the returned list in the first version.

```
import os

def dig(directory):
    c_path = []
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            c_path.append(path)
        else:
            dig(path)
    for entry in c_path:
        print entry

directory = str(input("Enter Directory: "))
files = dig(directory)
```

Comment: `dig(path)` returns a list of filenames but you ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not appending the recursive `dig()` output to your list (you just call it) try with:

```
def dig(directory):
    c_path = []
        for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            c_path.append(path)
        else:
            c_path += dig(path)
    return c_path
```

Although I'd suggest you to use [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) for this as it does all the dirty work for you.

Comment: But if that is the issue then how cum c_path is printing all the file names in the second version of the code.

Comment: @CHAANADKYA - you're printing the data in every call to your `dig()` function so it doesn't matter what you do with the returned list as it gets printed on the spot - your code is executing properly, it's just that you're not capturing the output from your recursed calls to `dig()` to store it in the return list.

Comment: Thanks a lot I Understood